# Symbol for the feasible set of portfolios in mean-variance analysis?

Tags: modern-portfolio-theory, reference-request, mean-variance, portfolio-selection, symbology

[image]

When we optimize some mean-variance efficient portfolio, it lies on the **efficient frontier** (blue line) which is considered superior to the feasible set of portfolios. The **feasible set** (red dots), on the other hand, is generated with random, rather than optimized, weight vectors.

Since there are tens of thousands of portfolios that lie within the feasible set, **what is the convention in mean-variance analysis** literature for symbolically expressing that a certain portfolio (weight vector) belongs to the feasible set? Is it:

$$w \in \mathcal{F}$$
where $\mathcal{F}$ is the feasible set?

Comment: Please note that the feasible set is simply the set of all portfolio combinations such that $\sum_i w_i =1$. I do not know of any specific symbol for that,though.

Comment: portfolio combinations that lie on the efficient frontier meet that criteria, so does that mean efficient portfolios (on the efficient frontier) are part of the feasible set?

Comment: Your notation seems correct based on p.4 of this paper: https://sites.math.washington.edu/~burke/crs/408/fin-proj/mark1.pdf